# What is the domain of $y=\sqrt x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For $f(x)=\sqrt x$ my teacher has the domain as $[0,+\infty)$. So the “$[$” means that $0$ is included but, why wouldn’t $+\infty$ be including, thus rendering $[0, \infty]$?

Comment: The finding of domains of expressions is an archaic task that we inherited from the time when the concept of functions wasn't yet developed, and that many schools haven't grown out of it. Even worse, in many cases they don't pose the problem properly and leave it ambiguous as you just noticed. To make the problem well posed it should read something like this: "Find a maximal subset of the reals for which the expression is defined and returns a real number." An ambiguous question like "find the domain of $\sqrt{x}$" can perfectly have yours as answer, as $\sqrt{x}:[0,\infty]\to[o,\infty]$ ...

Comment: ... is a well defined function.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Because "infinity" is not a number.

Comment: because infinity is not a **real** number

Comment: @N.S. An [affinely-extended-real-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)